# how to design form like google calender event in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

**I want design and implement this type of form ?**

[image]

Help me for that

i m new in android

Comment: do you know how to ask here ?

Comment: You can not ask others to do your requirement here. First try by yourself then ask what problem you are facing.

Comment: there is nothing special in that design. Just Views on the layout. Completely nothing to ask about. If you have some problem designing it, specify that problem.

Comment: i m tried many time but fail in design .. then i posted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using PercentageRelativeLayout.

Try this XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/from_layout"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="FROM"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.TextView" />

        <Spinner
            app:layout_widthPercent="60%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            style="@style/Platform.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner" />

        <Spinner
            app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner2"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            style="@style/Platform.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner" />

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/to_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/from_layout"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="TO"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.TextView" />

        <Spinner
            app:layout_widthPercent="60%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            style="@style/Platform.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner" />

        <Spinner
            app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner6"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner5"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            style="@style/Platform.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner" />

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/to_layout"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:text="ALL DAY"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            style="@style/Platform.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner" />
    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

You will get design like this:

[image]